# not getting path in debug console of vs code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, debugging, console

I am running my flutter project in vs code, while debugging them it is not showing the path:
[image]

In this picture, debug console is showing main.dart path. but it is my office pc if I run the project in my personal pc the path is not showing how to control this property in debug console.

I also tried word wrapper property in setting of vs code.

Comment: Based on you screenshot, it is common log when run first time the flutter app project. What is exact you need?

Comment: hi, the problem is that main.dart path is not showing in my debug console, if I tap on main.dart path it will take me to the corresponding code snippet. it is useful while handling error. because if I get error my debug console will also show the path of that error page. so that we can easily go to that code snippet. what i need is i want to get that path in my console. actually I am not getting it in my pc. is there a way to control that property.

Comment: the image i put above , have taken it from my collage pc.  i actually don't know how to get it for my debug console

Answer (score 0):

I don't have main.dart too like your screenshot.

[image]

But you don't need it, because every error will tell where is the part of it, like this.

[image]

Beside white scratch, you see `path-folder/file.dart:39:9`. Number 39 is line of your error.

It's reference to your statements, `because if I get error my debug console will also show the path of that error page. so that we can easily go to that code snippet.`

Comment: what ever you are telling is correct, but instead of reading and searching for the line if we found a path we can easily navigate to the file by simple tap , that is why I am asking how to control that path  in debug console